# Outlook add-in not showing up for SharePoint Group mailbox

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

We have custom Outlook add-in which is displayed when user selects any email message inside Office Outlook client or inside outlook.office.com browser.

I see that Outlook add-in is not displayed when user selects an email present in the SharePoint Group's mailbox either from Outlook client or inside browser.

I tried adding SupportsSharedFolder (thinking it may support Group mailbox) referring stackoverflow question but that too is not working for Group Mailbox. [Publishing Outlook add-in which uses Outlook preview element - SupportsSharedFolders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55471281/publishing-outlook-add-in-which-uses-outlook-preview-element-supportssharedfol/55480151)

```
<SupportsSharedFolders>true</SupportsSharedFolders>
```

I would like to know if Outlook add-ins are supported by SharePoint Group mailbox or not?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

These folders are not supported by Outlook web add-ins (as they are not shared folders).

Feature requests on Tech Community are considered, when the dev team go through the planning process. Use the github label: `Type: product feature request` at https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions .